# Create an array of words which also have numeric values in C

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program which asks a user to enter the 4 colors of the bands on a given resistance in order to calculate the equivalent resistance in ohms. There are 12 possible colors. Here is a picture to help illustrate: http://www.researchcell.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/resistor-color-code-band.jpg . This said, for the problem, I will only take into consideration the tolerances of the Gold and Silver bands. Here is what I have so far. My teacher gave me this assignment without explaining arrays, so I was left on my own for this one...
For the first two bands, Gold and Silver are invalid colors. Once the user enters a correct color, I would like to be able to go and retreive the same color entered in the array, which I will then associate to the corresponding value (as shown in the picture linked above). The end result, after the four colors are entered, would be the value of the resistance in ohms... Thank you very much, I really, really appreciate your help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    char *BANDS_1_2_3[12] = {"Black", "Brown", "Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue",                      "Violet", "Gray", "White", "Gold", "Silver"};
    int choice;
    char band1, band2, band3, band4;

    printf("Please choose one of the following options: \n\n1. Calculate the resistance \n2. Help \n3. Exit \n\n");
    scanf("%d", &choix);


    if(choice==1)
    {
        printf("Please enter the color of the first band:"); scanf("%s", &band1);

        if((band1 == BANDS_1_2_3[11]) && (band1 == BANDS_1_2_3[12]))
        {
            printf("Invalid color. Please try again:"); scanf("%s", &band1);
        }
        else if
        {

        }
```

Comment: You're going to need to create some sort of mapping of a string to your value.  I would recommend a struct that holds the pairs.  Also your comparison of `band1 == BANDS_1_2_3[12]` will not work as you anticipate in C.  You need to use `strcmp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few problems:

1. Your input buffers, `band1`, `band2`, etc, need to be strings, not chars - change:

   ```
   char band1, band2, band3, band4;
   ```

to:

```
    char band[32];
```

and just use `band` wherever you currently use `band1`, `band2`, etc.

2. You need to use `strcmp` to compare strings, so change e.g.

   ```
   (band1 == BANDS_1_2_3[11])
   ```

to:

```
    strcmp(band1, BANDS_1_2_3[11]) == 0
```

3. Your logic is wrong here:

   ```
   if((band1 == BANDS_1_2_3[11]) && (band1 == BANDS_1_2_3[12]))
   ```

This should be:

```
    if(strcmp(band1, BANDS_1_2_3[11]) == 0 || strcmp(band1, BANDS_1_2_3[12]) == 0)
                                          ^^^^
```

Note the use of logical OR rather than logical AND.